# How to convert integer to string using current culture in .NET?

Tags: .net, localization, globalization

How do i convert an integer to a localized string in .NET?

Exempli gratia:

```
Int64 value = 12345678901;

value.ToString();  
   // returns "12345678901", should be "123,4567,8901"

value.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);  
   // returns "12345678901", should be "123,4567,8901"

value.ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")) 
   // returns "12345678901", should be "12,345,678,901"

value.ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-CH"))
   // returns "12345678901", should be "12'345'678'901"

value.ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("te-IN"))
   // returns "12345678901", should be "12,34,56,78,901"
```

How do i convert an integer (or float) to a localized string in .NET?

### Bonus Chatter

Unique list of number formats in the world:

- 12 345 678 901
- 12,34,56,78,901
- 12,345,678,901
- 12.345.678.901
- 12?345?678?901
- 123,4567,8901
- 12'345'678'901

Additional bonus information where these culture settings can be found in .NET:

```
CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US").NumberFormat.NumberGroupSizes = { 3 }
CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US").NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ","

CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("te-IN").NumberFormat.NumberGroupSizes = { 3, 2 }
CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("te-IN").NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ","

CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("te-IN").NumberFormat.NumberGroupSizes = { 3 }
CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("te-IN").NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = "'"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the "N" [standard format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) with a precision of 0.

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main() 
    {
        long value = 12345678901;
        string text = value.ToString("N0");
        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
```

Result (on my UK machine):

```
12,345,678,901
```

That will take the current culture into account for various aspects. You can specify a culture separately, of course.

**Edit**: Generalized form for specific cultures:

```
value.ToString("N0", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-CH"));
```